# How can i install Sqitch on Centos 7 offline

Tags: centos7, sqitch

In my client Centos 7 machine in need to install sqitch, but in offline environment have no clue how to do that!

Comment: [Docker](https://sqitch.org/download/docker/)?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution which worked for me, where i am trying to generate a Sqitch bundle folder which we will have a working build of Sqitch which you can use in other centos 7 machines having the same Arch.

```
# yum install gcc

# yum install perl-DBD-Pg

# cpan

cpan[1]> install HTML::Entities
```

#### Extract tar

```
# cd /{extracted_dir}/

# perl Build.PL

# ./Build installdeps

# ./Build bundle --install_base sqitch_bundle --dual_life 1 --with postgres
```

Now you have sqitch_bundle folder inside App-Sqitch-v1.0.0 folder which got extracted in the above step, this sqitch_bundle folder you can tar it and share with other Centos  7, having  Perl enabled."

After which, Sqitch can be run from

```
# ./sqitch_bundle/bin/sqitch
```

Now to access as regular we need to add the Path in .bashrc or .bash_profile, Example

```
PATH="/opt/App-Sqitch-v1.0.0/sqitch_bundle/bin/:$PATH"
```